Refresh materialized concurrently suddenly stopped working
I have about 10 materialized views that get refreshed every day. One of them actually every 10 minutes
The problem is that suddenly, the concurrently stopped working. I get the following error
SQL Error [42501]: ERROR: permission denied for schema ogr_system_tables
Where: PL/pgSQL function ogr_system_tables.event_trigger_function_for_metadata() line 8 at 
SQL statement
SQL statement "DROP TABLE pg_temp_63.pg_temp_39246664_2, pg_temp_63.pg_temp_39246664"

This is a very strange permission error, since I am using an admin account. Even If I grant myself permission on that schema and try again, the error does not go away. I tried rebooting the database and it still does not work
The bizarre thing is that if I refresh those views without using the concurrently, it works fine. Problem is that many tables get accessed constantly so the concurrently is needed

Check the log files, someone changed the permissions

maybe ogr_system_tables.event_trigger_function_for_metadata() has a security definer, so it doesn't run as you but as another user?

@FrankHeikens  looks like running ALTER EVENT TRIGGER ogr_system_tables_event_trigger_for_metadata DISABLE;
has solved he issue. I guess the question now is if I actually need this trigger event
